# Undefined index: userAgent in CakeSession

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

When trying to call the method

```
CakeSession->destroy()
```

I'm getting this error:

> Undefined index: userAgent

The Stack Trace is as follows:

> lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php : 332
>
> lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php : 632
>
> lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php : 192
>
> lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php : 438
>
> lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php : 427

I've followed it down to to the method

```
CakeSession->_validAgentAndTime()
```

and that index is really missing -- anyhow, I got no idea how to get it there. It only seems to occur when running PHPUnit Tests.
Sometimes, if I run another test after this error and to back, it works once and then keeps failing again.

I'm using CakePHP 2.2.3 and PHPUnit 3.7.10 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older browsers and bespoke applications may provide strange or no UserAgent, but you can disable the UserAgent aspect of CakePHP in the app/core/config.php file:

```
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
```

If you want to keep the UserAgent intact for your tests, you can use the below to debug ...

env('HTTP_USER_AGENT');

Comment: Just found out the reason for my problem being something different (we were overwriting some session data) -- anyhow, figured this to be a possible solution so thanks!